# cURL command units of Dload speed?

Tags: macos, terminal, curl

When I run curl I sometimes see a progress meter like this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 38 11.0M   38 4319k    0     0  20189      0  0:09:31  0:03:39  0:05:52 18472
```

What unit is Average Dload given in?

An answer which also contains a link to another page explaining the entirety of the progress meter (what each section means) would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out (the difficulty was in comprehending just how slow my internet really is): Average Dload is measured in Bytes per second.